# Getting Available Hardware for BM's across all datacenters

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Looking through the API, I'm having trouble finding whether I can find certain hardware availability across datacenters.

I'm looking specifically whether or not certain RAM, CPU, Hard drive and uplink speed configurations are available in all datacenters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this request:

```
https://$USER:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects
```

It returns hardware information and its avaialability in the datacenters.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was using this earlier but i see that it returns information on the various packages. if I see one package with a Xeon 32 core CPU only available in 5 DC's, does this mean that this CPU isn't available in the other DC's?

Comment: that's rigth, that package wiith Xeon 32 is only available in the listed DCs

Comment: Thank you. If I order a BM do I have to pick a package or can I order that Xeon CPU and change out the ram, hard drive etc within the DC's that the Xeon is available in?

Comment: In your order request you need to specify the package (a package can have several flavors of servers eg. Xeon E5-2690, Xeon E52620, etc) and you need to specify the server (e.g. Xeon E5-2690 ) and you can change the the ram, hard drives etc. see this blog for more information http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to check how much storage is left for every datacenter? 
If i put an order in for a BM or VM, if I'm even able to create the order in the datacenter if it has capacity.

Comment: that is not possible using API if you want to make sure that there is enought room in a datacenter you need to open a ticket in softlayer control portal and ask them to the softlayer's sales guys

Comment: I see how to get price id's from a package but is there a way to get price id's a bare metal server has? Looking to grab all the price id's of components an existing bare metal server has to create another order via json

Comment: there is a method only for virtual servers http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getOrderTemplate for bare metals there is no such method

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the capacity question I asked before. Is there a way to check how many volumes are left per account on softlayer to provision VMs?

Comment: No, you need to ask softlayer